# How to do Post for https using Apache client

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap-client, java-client

Hi i am trying to do **post request in SOAP** for **HTTPS** using **Apache client**.However I can do easily with **HTTP** with Apache client.But getting **difficult** with **HTPPS**.I have tried google a lots but not getting the proper documentation.Somewhere i found, but in that they have used deprecated class.
**Somebody tell me how to do post request in SOAP for HTTPS using apache client or simple java with explanation of SSL(Getting trust certificate)**.
**It is better if i will get the working example.**
Suggestions are always appreciable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  StackOverflow works best if you post what you have done so far. Questions that look like "please write my code for me" (even if you didn't intend it that way) generally get downvoted and put on hold as off-topic.  If you show what you've tried and explain what isn't working (include stack trace and/or error messages where appropriate) you are ***much*** more likely to get help.

Comment: please put some code what u have tried till now??

Comment: @rish Ok  i m providing you the URL from where i have tried to do the code. http://prasans.info/2014/06/making-https-call-using-apache-httpclient/

Comment: @rish please look over that and try to implement in your own way.Thanks for response

Comment: @MdNoorshid what's wrong with this link?? It's working fine for me

Comment: @rish Its really amazing if it is working for you,Actually here some classes used is deprecated.Hope you might be noticed.

Comment: @rish i have added my approach of doing the code with the same url i have provided.Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops my request was wrong actually.
Code is working fine